# Why balances in Node-Binance-Api not working?

Tags: node.js, binance

I tried to interact in Node js with the Binance Testnet Spot Api. I use "node-binance-api" but it prints only weird stuff when I want to buy sell or get the balance. Can you help me with that issue. I also set up a raspberry pi with the same code and it works on the raspberry pi but why not on windows. Here is my code:

```
const Binance = require('node-binance-api');

const binance = new Binance().options({
    APIKEY: '#####',
    APISECRET: '#####',
    verbose: true,
    urls: {
      base: "https://testnet.binance.vision/api/", // remove this to trade on mainnet
      combineStream: 'wss://testnet.binance.vision/stream?streams=',
    stream: 'wss://testnet.binance.vision/ws/'
    },
  });

binance.balance((error, balances) => {
    if ( error ) return console.log(error);
    console.info("balances()", balances);
    if(balances.USDT.available != undefined){
    console.info("USDT balance: ", balances.USDT.available);
    }
});
```

And here is the output:

```
 proxyHeaderExclusiveList: []
    },
    setHeader: [Function (anonymous)],
    hasHeader: [Function (anonymous)],
    getHeader: [Function (anonymous)],
    removeHeader: [Function (anonymous)],
    pool: { 'https:': [Agent] },
    dests: [],
    __isRequestRequest: true,
    _callback: [Function (anonymous)],
    uri: Url {
      protocol: 'https:',
      slashes: true,
      auth: null,
      host: 'testnet.binance.vision',
      port: null,
      hostname: 'testnet.binance.vision',
      hash: null,
      search: '?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
      query: 'timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
      pathname: '/api/v3/account',
      path: '/api/v3/account?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
      href: 'https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/account?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538'
    },
    proxy: null,
    tunnel: true,
    setHost: true,
    originalCookieHeader: undefined,
    _disableCookies: true,
    _jar: undefined,
    port: 443,
    host: 'testnet.binance.vision',
    url: Url {
      protocol: 'https:',
      slashes: true,
      auth: null,
      host: 'testnet.binance.vision',
      port: null,
      hostname: 'testnet.binance.vision',
      hash: null,
      search: '?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
      query: 'timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
      pathname: '/api/v3/account',
      path: '/api/v3/account?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
      href: 'https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/account?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538'
    },
    path: '/api/v3/account?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
    httpModule: {
      Agent: [Function: Agent],
      globalAgent: [Agent],
      Server: [Function: Server],
      createServer: [Function: createServer],
      get: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    agentClass: [Function: Agent],
    agentOptions: { keepAlive: true },
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _started: true,
    href: 'https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/account?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
    req: <ref *3> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /api/v3/account?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Node Binance API)\r\n' +
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' +
        'X-MBX-APIKEY: VaL2HWmy6TpwD5UVwZ53XWIpSpTBuYuIHN5bSuMRAHcdapLwZRqdW0JYM8UuNIkX\r\n' +
        'host: testnet.binance.vision\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: {},
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/v3/account?timestamp=1629799331717&recvWindow=5000&signature=cc76599a0f29728adcd76cb0a009c8e42e6d65e4944abc12d701ebc494c59538',
      _ended: true,
      res: [Circular *2],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'testnet.binance.vision',
      protocol: 'https:',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    ntick: true,
    timeoutTimer: null,
    response: [Circular *2],
    originalHost: 'testnet.binance.vision',
    originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
    responseContent: [Circular *2],
    _destdata: true,
    _ended: true,
    _callbackCalled: true,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
  caseless: Caseless {
    dict: {
      'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'content-length': '88',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      date: 'Tue, 24 Aug 2021 10:02:10 GMT',
      server: 'nginx',
      'x-mbx-uuid': '07e06b9a-8a30-4b81-a8e7-02bb3452ef16',
      'x-mbx-used-weight': '12',
      'x-mbx-used-weight-1m': '12',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate being referred to the docs but take a look through them. It says to wrap the entry point of your application with `useServerTime()`

```
    await binance.useServerTime();
    binance.balance((error, balances) => {
        if ( error ) return console.error(error);
        console.info("balances()", balances);
        console.info("BNB balance: ", balances.BNB.available);
    });
```

also `Binance.info = { timeOffset: -2000 };` this is in the node-binance-api you can edit the offset and it will help too! Sorry this was a year later!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older issue, but unfortunately I didn't find answer, which could help me. But I was able to resolve my issue and here are few steps, which could help others:

- Make sure you copied correct API Key - when I was copying it from Binance I had at the end of key character `<`, so ofc I was getting error telling me "...wrong API key..."
- in your Binance API Management use option `Restrict access to trusted IPs only` and add there your Global IP address
  **EDIT**: This point is not necessary.
- as it's in documentation, add to your setup

```
binance.options({
...
  useServerTime: true,
  recvWindow: 60000 // Set a higher recvWindow to increase response timeout
});
```

- sync time on your machine

```
Right-click on the clock and click on Adjust date/time.
Or you can go to Start > Settings > Time & language > Date & time.
Under Synchronize your clock, click button "Sync now".
```